# Is it possible to play NBA 2K13(PC) with two player?

Tags: nba2k13

Is it possible to play NBA 2K13 on the PC with two players? I'm thinking like using splitscreens, using two controllers, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can plug in two controllers or have one player use the controller and another use the keyboard. The game will put different colored rings under the players that each controller is controlling.

There is no split-screen mode; you will both share the same camera whether you play on the same team or against each other.